# Cannot Perform Multiple Queries On Firebase Database to Display in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to query the most recent children in my Firebase database and then sort that limit of recent children by a child value. I understand that the Cloud Firestore has recently been released, and that querying features continue to evolve on the Firebase Realtime Database as well.

I am using the FirebaseUI FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, and within that adapter you must enter a query. I am tweaking to add 2 queries to my RecyclerView. I am doing so as follows:

```
mFireAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Poll, PollHolder>(
    Poll.class, R.layout.latest_item, PollHolder.class, 
    mBaseRef.child("Polls").limitToLast(3).orderByChild("vote_count"))
```

Unfortunately, it is not working, as it is first ordering the **whole** database by the child value and then displaying those 5 values. Essentially, the result is flipped in terms of what I am seeking: I want to query by limiting to the most recent X children and THEN sort those by child value. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Edit:

Here is my Firebase Database. Essentially, I want to limit the query to the last 3 items in that database, and then sort those 3 items by vote count. I then want them to populate the RecyclerView accordingly. I am trying to do that in the code snippet listed above, but instead of actually limiting to the last 3 items in the database it is querying the whole database.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your requirement. Are you looking to load the items with the highest vote count? (it might help if you post a snippet of the JSON you're querying)

Comment: Frank, I have included the database and additional detail on what I am trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah OK, I understand now. It's not possible to get the latest three items (which requires ordering by key) in order of their score (a child property). A query can only order/filter on one property. But sorting the latest three items in a list on the score shouldn't be difficult to do client-side.

Comment: Thanks Frank, does this mean that under the current setup I cannot generate a recyclerview that limits and sorts? It has to be one or the other?

Comment: Yes. See some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D+multiple+conditions

Comment: Thanks again. So it doesn't seem possible, any plans to add this type of query capability?

Comment: Hi Frank - Just wanted to reach out and see if this option is yet available. I am using the latest Firebase library 10.2.1. I want to populate a RecyclerView using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, first limiting to recent items in my Database (.limitToLast) and then sorting those recent items (.orderByChild).

Comment: Hi Frank - with the announcement of Cloud Firestore I wanted to reach out on this question again. I have also read about the third-party library querybase. Essentially, I want to first limit the results displayed in the RecyclerView to a set number of the latest items added to Firebase, to capture the most recent items. Then, after I have captured the most recent items, I want to sort by a child (vote count). Thanks again!

Comment: With Cloud Firestore (and the Firebase SDKs for it) you can order by multiple properties. That might be enough to implement your use-case. If you're having problems with it, post a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Frank, is this a new feature? I remember it was previously not possible .orderBy() and .limitToLast() simultaneously.

Comment: Cloud Firestore is a new product, launched yesterday. :-)   Note that it's a separate product though, it's not a new feature of the Firebase Realtime Database. Queries on the latter are still limited to a single property. For your options there, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Got it - I was reading the documentation and it mentioned complex querying. I wasn't sure if that encompassed what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks again.